# Socket.IO aumento de latencia despues de unos mensajes

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, socket, socket.io, networking

estoy haciendo una app con socket.IO y react (no va al caso) de mensajeria, al comienzo esta funciona perfecto y la información va y viene correctamente, pero al mandar 10 mensajes seguidos, mas o menos, el socket del cliente empieza a tardar muchisimo en recibir, el servidor lo envia en tiempo y el wifi tambien, que puede ser? hay alguna configuracion especial?

[image]

aca dejo un screenshot del network de la consola donde se ve como colapsa y empieza a tardar minutos en recibir un mensaje tan corto, ademas por culpa de esto la pagina entera queda lageada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @Lucas Aldazabal,

Tu caso es parecido al que padecí yo.

A mi lo que me ocurría es que los eventos que crea el Socket no se eliminaba, eso hace que se acumulasen y me generase perdida de memoria (memory leak). Ocurriendo que los mensajes tardasen muchos y el programa se iba saturando cada vez mas.

La solución que obtuve fue eliminar el evento que crea el socket cuando recibe un mensaje. Te muestro un poco de código para que puedas entenderlo:

```
const getMessage = (data) => {
    console.log('Message: ', data);
    socket.removeListener('message', getMessage)
}


socket.on('message', getMessage);

//.............

socket.emit('message', 'Un, dos, tres, pollito ingles...')
```

Espero que con esto te ayude a encontrar una solución.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Lo acabo de poner y funciona Perfecto!

Answer (score -1):

tengo otro problema, ahora cuando un usuario manda miles de mensajes no hay ningun lag, pero si luego de eso, ese mismo usuario recibe uno se lagea todo, que podria ser?

Comment: Si tenes otra pregunta, por favor hacela presionando sobre el botón [Hacer una pregunta](//es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). La sección de respuestas no debe ser usada para hacer una pregunta.

Comment: perdon a ambos, soy nuevo en el foro y  como la segunda duda venia unida a la anterior fue que no cree otra nueva